# Groovy AST Transformation, add calls to doubleValue() selectively within expression

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

Assume this expression within a groovy file:

```
class MyNumber extends Number {
    double doSomeThingSpecial() {...}

    double doubleValue() { ... }
    // ...
}

double expr( MyNumber n ) {
   return Math.sqrt( n ) + myFunc( n );
}

double myFunc( MyNumber n ) {
    return n.doSomeThingSpecial();
}
```

The code above won't work as Math.sqrt( ... ) expects double as a parameter.

Is it possible (and how) to do an AST Transformation so that the content of def expr( MyNumber n ) is tranformed as follows:

```
double expr( MyNumber n ) {
   return Math.sqrt( n.doubleValue() ) + myFunc( n );
}
```

... or any other idea how to solve this would be welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple metaprogramming might suffice. Use an [extension](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+an+extension+module) if you are under `@TypeChecked`/`@CompileStatic`

```
class MyNumber extends Number {

    { Math.metaClass.static.sqrt = { MyNumber m -> Math.sqrt(m.doubleValue()) } }

    double doSomeThingSpecial() { 20 }

    double doubleValue() { 9 }

    float floatValue() { assert false, 'not implemented' }
    int intValue() { assert false, 'not implemented' }
    long longValue() { assert false, 'not implemented' }
}

double expr( MyNumber n ) {
   return Math.sqrt( n ) + myFunc( n );
}

double myFunc( MyNumber n ) {
    return n.doSomeThingSpecial();
}

n = new MyNumber()

assert Math.sqrt(n) == 3

assert expr(n) == 23
```

Comment: What I'd like to achieve is that the behaviour would apply to any method call taking double as argument not only for Math.sqrt(). Interesting thing that I noticed is that if MyNumber extends BigDecimal, then groovy with coerce the arguments to double automatically, this however doesn't work when extending from Number

Comment: Happens to Strings and Booleans too. Seems like you want something like [Scala's implicits](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/implicit-conversions-in-scala.html). Have you thought about mixing functionality to the Double class instead?

Comment: I'm no specialist in AST, but i don't think it solves this. You can iterate through all the tree, but some parameters might be dynamic, of the `MyNumber` class, without typing. You'd never know.

Comment: I am a groovy newbie, I tried the @Mixin approach but did not work (or did something wrong)

Comment: What is your use case? Is it enough if you add methods to the `Double` class?

Comment: Yes adding method to Double would be enough, the MyNumber implementation however is done in java and not in groovy. :S

Comment: Totally forgot about this thread, sorry. Anyway, you can use [ExpandoMetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass) to add methods to Double class or an [Extension](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+an+extension+module)